# Is there a way to have FileChannels close automatically?

Tags: java, timer, nio, filechannel

I am currently developing an application that requires random access to many (60k-100k) relatively large files. 
Since opening and closing streams is a rather costly operation, I'd prefer to keep the FileChannels for the largest files open until they are no longer needed.

The problem is that since this kind of behaviour is not covered by Java 7's try-with statement, I'm required to close all the FileChannels manually. 
But that is becoming increasingly too complicated since the same files could be accessed concurrently throughout the software.

I have implemented a ChannelPool class that can keep track of opened FileChannel instances for each registered Path. The ChannelPool can then be issued to close those channels whose Path is only weakly referenced by the pool itself in certain intervals. 
I would prefer an event-listener approach, but I'd also rather not have to listen to the GC.

The [FileChannelPool](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/wicket/releases/wicket-1.5-RC5.1/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/pageStore/FileChannelPool.java) from Apache Commons doesn't address my problem, because channels still need to be closed manually.

Is there a more elegant solution to this problem? And if not, how can my implementation be improved?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class ChannelPool {

    private static final ChannelPool defaultInstance = new ChannelPool();

    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, ChannelRef> channels;
    private final Timer timer;

    private ChannelPool(){
        channels = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        timer = new Timer();
    }

    public static ChannelPool getDefault(){
        return defaultInstance;
    }

    public void initCleanUp(){
        // wait 2 seconds then repeat clean-up every 10 seconds.
        timer.schedule(new CleanUpTask(this), 2000, 10000);
    }

    public void shutDown(){
        // must be called manually.
        timer.cancel();
        closeAll();
    }

    public FileChannel getChannel(Path path){
        ChannelRef cref = channels.get(path.toString());
        System.out.println("getChannel called " + channels.size());

        if (cref == null){
            cref = ChannelRef.newInstance(path);
            if (cref == null){
                // failed to open channel
                return null;
            }
            ChannelRef oldRef = channels.putIfAbsent(path.toString(), cref);
            if (oldRef != null){
                try{
                    // close new channel and let GC dispose of it
                    cref.channel().close();
                    System.out.println("redundant channel closed");
                }
                catch (IOException ex) {}
                cref = oldRef;
            }
        }
        return cref.channel();
    }

    private void remove(String str) {   
        ChannelRef ref = channels.remove(str);
        if (ref != null){
            try {
                ref.channel().close();
                System.out.println("old channel closed");
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {}
        }
    }

    private void closeAll() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, ChannelRef> e : channels.entrySet()){
            remove(e.getKey());
        }
    }

    private void maintain() {
        // close channels for derefenced paths
        for (Map.Entry<String, ChannelRef> e : channels.entrySet()){
            ChannelRef ref = e.getValue();
            if (ref != null){
                Path p = ref.pathRef().get();
                if (p == null){
                    // gc'd
                    remove(e.getKey());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static class ChannelRef{

        private FileChannel channel;
        private WeakReference<Path> ref;

        private ChannelRef(FileChannel channel, WeakReference<Path> ref) {
            this.channel = channel;
            this.ref = ref;
        }

        private static ChannelRef newInstance(Path path) {
            FileChannel fc;
            try {
                fc = FileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.READ);
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                return null;
            }
            return new ChannelRef(fc, new WeakReference<>(path));

        }

        private FileChannel channel() {
            return channel;
        }

        private WeakReference<Path> pathRef() {
            return ref;
        }
    }

    private static class CleanUpTask extends TimerTask {

        private ChannelPool pool;

        private CleanUpTask(ChannelPool pool){
            super();
            this.pool = pool;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            pool.maintain();
            pool.printState();
        }
    }

    private void printState(){
        System.out.println("Clean up performed. " + channels.size() + " channels remain. -- " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        for (Map.Entry<String, ChannelRef> e : channels.entrySet()){
            ChannelRef cref = e.getValue();
            String out = "open: " + cref.channel().isOpen() + " - " + cref.channel().toString();
            System.out.println(out);
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT:
Thanks to [fge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1093528/fge)'s answer I have now exactly what I needed. Thanks!

```
import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;
import com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader;
import com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache;
import com.google.common.cache.RemovalListener;
import com.google.common.cache.RemovalNotification;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class Channels {

    private static final LoadingCache<Path, FileChannel> channelCache = 
            CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .weakKeys()
            .removalListener(
                new RemovalListener<Path, FileChannel>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onRemoval(RemovalNotification<Path, FileChannel> removal) {
                        FileChannel fc = removal.getValue();
                        try {
                            fc.close();
                        }
                        catch (IOException ex) {}
                    }
                }
            )
            .build(
                new CacheLoader<Path, FileChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    public FileChannel load(Path path) throws IOException {
                        return FileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.READ);
                    }
                }
            );

    public static FileChannel get(Path path){
        try {
            return channelCache.get(path);
        }
        catch (ExecutionException ex){}
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could use a `LoadingCache` from Guava? It has removal listeners, expiration after write/access etc

Comment: I wouldn't have multiple threads accessing files concurrently in the first place. I would have one thread extract the information you need from them once.  Just loading 100K files once is time consuming enough. If you have a slow HDD, it is a nightmare for performance.

Comment: Note: unless you have a very fast drive, multiple threads won't make it go any faster, so you may as well using just one thread, read one file at a time and avoid all these issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here:

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained

You can use a `LoadingCache` with a removal listener which would close the channel for you when it expires, and you can specify expiry after access or write.